# GoogleCloud Kubernetes node cannot connect to Redis Memorystore possibly due to overlap in IP ranges

Tags: redis, kubernetes, gcloud, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a GoogleCloud Kubernetes cluster consisting of multiple nodes and a GoogleCloud Redis Memorystore. Distributed over these nodes are replicas of a pod containing a container that needs to connect to the Redis Memorystore. I have noticed that one of the nodes is not able to connect to Redis, i.e. any container in a pod on that node cannot connect to Redis.

The Redis Memorystore has the following properties:

- IP address: `10.0.6.12`
- Instance IP address range: `10.0.6.8/29` (`10.0.6.8` - `10.0.6.15`)

The node from which no connection to Redis can be made has the following properties:

- Internal IP: `10.132.0.5`
- PodCIDR: `10.0.6.0/24` (`10.0.6.0` - `10.0.6.255`)

I assume this problem is caused by the overlap in IP ranges of the Memorystore and this node. Is this assumption correct?

If this is the problem I would like to change the IP range of the node.
I have tried to do this by editing `spec.podCIRD` in the node config:

```
$ kubectl edit node <node-name>
```

However this did not work and resulted in the error message:

```
# * spec.podCIDR: Forbidden: node updates may not change podCIDR except from "" to valid
# * []: Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity (or configSource, if the DynamicKubeletConfig feature gate is enabled)
```

Is there another way to change the IP range of an existing Kubernetes node? If so, how?

Sometimes I need to temporarily increase the number of pods in a cluster. When I do this I want to prevent Kubernetes from creating a new node with the IP range `10.0.6.0/24`.
Is it possible to tell the Kubernetes cluster to not create new nodes with the IP range `10.0.6.0/24`? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Not for a node. The podCidr gets defined when you install your network overlay in initial steps when setting up a new cluster.
- Yes for the cluster. but it's not that easy. You have to change the podCidr for the network overlay in your whole cluster. It's a tricky process that can be done, but if you are doing that you might as well deploy a new cluster. Keep in mind that some network overlays require a very specific PodCidr. For example, Calico requires `192.168.0.0/16`

You could:

1. Create a new cluster with a new cidr and move your workloads gradually.
2. Change the IP address cidr where your GoogleCloud Redis Memorystore lives.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I decided to create a new redis memorystore with a different IP address cidr.